# JVM runs in eclipse, crashes outside with SIGSEGV

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jvm, segmentation-fault

I am using the library [native-tray-adapter](https://github.com/taksan/native-tray-adapter), which requires the library [jni-utils-1.0](https://github.com/taksan/jni-utils) to ensure that icons in Ubuntu don´t have a transparent background.

My program creates a menu with a close menu item the closes the program. When I run the program in eclipse it works fine and I can interact with the icon without any problems. When I export the file to a runnable jar the java virtual machine crashes when I try to close the program, the program is able to display the menu from a right click however clicking the menu causes the crash.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6d3f746, pid=6193, tid=2121870192
```

This happens in both the sun and open runtime environments. I also tried running the virtual machine as client and cacao, in client the problem was the same, however in cacao the virtual machine did not crash but it did not react properly to any interaction with the icon.

When I ran the virtual machine with argument -Xcheck:jni I got the error message:

```
WARNING in native method: JNI call made with exception pending
FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI
Aborted
```

I assume that the problem lies in the jni-utils library however I don´t understand why eclipse is able to run the program without problems and then it crashes outside of the environment.

I have checked the directory of the virtual machine in eclipse>help>about>installation details>configuration and this matches the directory of the command

```
$ which java
```

some extra details

```
os: ubuntu 11.10 
eclipse version: 3.7.0 
eclipse library: java6-openjdk 
java version: "1.6.0_26"
```

if more information is desired, feel free to ask. There is the error log however I don´t know how helpful that would be and what parts I would need to post.

Any help into why this might be happening, a way to make the virtual machine identical to that of eclipse, or another method to remove the white background that is shown in ubuntu using the standard Java TrayIcon´s would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I found that a problem lied in the way I was exporting the jar file. When I selected in eclipse jar exporting:

1. extract required libraries into generated JAR

   or
2. copy required libraries into a subfolder next to generated JAR

I was able to interact with the icon correctly. I'm still not exactly sure what the problem is, as I thought that linking would still behave the same independent libraries are packaged inside or outside the JAR.

Is this an error in the eclipse packaging or is there some other problem?

cheers

Answer (score -1):

To Quote from http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html -->:
This signal is generated when a program tries to read or write outside the memory that is allocated for it, or to write memory that can only be read. (Actually, the signals only occur when the program goes far enough outside to be detected by the system's memory protection mechanism.) The name is an abbreviation for “segmentation violation”.

Common ways of getting a SIGSEGV condition include dereferencing a null or uninitialized pointer, or when you use a pointer to step through an array, but fail to check for the end of the array. It varies among systems whether dereferencing a null pointer generates SIGSEGV or SIGBUS